# Prove that $S_{\triangle APQ}=xy.$

Tags: geometry

[image]

> Prove that $S_{\triangle APQ} = xy$ when $BP=x, DQ=y, \square ABCD = \text{quadrate}$.

> Hint 1.

> Hint 1. Set $\overline{AB} = a.$ Then, Do something at $\triangle APQ.$

> Hint 2.

> Hint 2. something = Pythagorean Theorem

> Hint 3.

> Hint 3. Did it? Then, Just think about the area of $\triangle APQ.$

> Solution.

> \begin{align} & \text{let } \overline{AB}=a. \\ & (a-x)^2+(a-y)^2=(x+y)^2, 2a^2-2ax-2ay+x^2+y^2=x^2+2xy+y^2. \\ & \therefore 2a^2-2ax-2ay=2xy, a^2-ax-ay=xy. \\ \ \\ & S_{\triangle APQ} = \dfrac {(a-x)(a-y)} {2} = \dfrac {a^2-ax-ay+xy} {2} = \dfrac {xy+xy} {2} = xy. _{\blacksquare} \end{align}

Comment: You can self-answer your question and it is encouraged if you have a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\triangle BPC\simeq \triangle TPC$ and $\triangle DQC \simeq\triangle TQC$, hence the area of the non-yellow part is just $2(S_{BPC} + S_{DQC})= ax+ay=a(x+y)$.

Thus the area of the yellow part is just $$a^2 - a(x+y)=\frac{1}{2}(a-x)(a-y)\Leftrightarrow a^2-a(x+y)=xy$$

Pythagorean is not needed.

Comment: Oh, there was an easier solution! I haven't thought about this, thanks...!